# How do I only check one checkbox at a time within a ListView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, checkbox

I have a ListView that contains 3 checkboxes per row. I want to set it up so that only one checkbox can be selected at a time.  Here is my current CodeBehind...

```
Public Class MyClass

    Dim Checkbox1 As Checkbox
    Dim Checkbox2 As Checkbox
    Dim Checkbox3 As Checkbox

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        InitializeDisplay()

        If Not IsPostBack Then
           UpdateDisplay()
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub UpdateDisplay()

        Dim Table As DataTable
        Table = GetDataTable()

        ListView.DataSource = Table
        ListView.DataBind()  

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView_ItemDataBound( sender, e ) Handles ListView.ItemDataBound

        Dim item As ListViewItem = e.Item

        Checkbox1 = item.FindControl("Checkbox1")
        Checkbox2 = item.FindControl("Checkbox2")
        Checkbox3 = item.FindControl("Checkbox3")

    End Sub

    Public Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim Checkbox2 As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)
        Dim Checkbox3 As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)

        Checkbox2.Checked = False
        Checkbox3.Checked = False        

    End Sub

    Public Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim Checkbox1 As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)
        Dim Checkbox3 As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)

        Checkbox1.Checked = False
        Checkbox3.Checked = False        

    End Sub

    Public Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim Checkbox1 As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)
        Dim Checkbox2 As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)

        Checkbox1.Checked = False
        Checkbox2.Checked = False        

    End Sub

End Class
```

Actual WebForm ItemTemplate from the ListView

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Checkbox ID="CheckBox1" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
<asp:Checkbox ID="CheckBox2" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
<asp:Checkbox ID="CheckBox3" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Let me know if I need to include anything else.  Right now when I click a checkbox and another checkbox is selected then both are selected instead of just the new one... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: don't [radio buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xke2zw4x(v=vs.71).aspx) do this

Comment: @TomIngram, I attempted it with radio buttons and still had the same effect. Except they wouldn't "Uncheck", I would also like to use the checkboxes because they look better if possible. Thanks!

Comment: I think that as a user you expect to be able to make multiple selections from a group of checkboxes and a single selection from a group of radio buttons this has IMHO been an intrinsic UI design for many years [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/AFDZh/) for a demo using jquery to allow uncheckable radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set AutoPostBack="true" on each checkbox (Doco [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback.aspx)). Otherwise, your server side code will never run until a postback is triggered in some other way.

I would personally prefer to use jQuery to do it, to avoid a round-trip to the server. To do this, try something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(eventData){
        var checked = $(eventData.currentTarget).prop("checked");
        if(checked === "checked"){
             $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);//uncheck everything.
             $(eventData.currentTarget).prop("checked", "checked");//recheck this one. 
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done one, im sure you can figure out whats required for the rest.  Also this could be neatened by creating one handler for all 3 checkboxes

Im not great with .net, but i know its possible.

.....

Public Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Dim Checkbox2 As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)
        Dim Checkbox3 As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)

Checkbox2.Checked = Not sender.checked
        Checkbox3.Checked = Not sender.checked

End Sub

Although as mentioned above, radio buttons are more suited to this application usually.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(eventData){

        var checked = $(eventData.currentTarget).prop("checked");

        if(checked){

             $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);//uncheck everything.
             $(eventData.currentTarget).prop("checked", "checked");//recheck this one. 
        }
   });

});
```